# Weird comparison between MOSFETs for ESC

Tags: mosfet, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller

I am designing an ESC (electronic speed controller) for a BLDC motor which is 3500W, 85A and 44V. The first thing is to choose the MOSFET, which should be easy.

I first found the IRFS7534, which has a 1.6 mohm R<sub>DS(on)</sub> and 255 amp. I viewed its family and found IRFS7530, which has a 1.15 mohm R<sub>DS(on)</sub> and 338 amps.

But for a reason, most sellers on AliExpress claim that IRFS7534 handles more current than IRFS7530, which is the opposite in the datasheet.

I move on searching and see some ESC from manufactures and see that they use NTMFS5C612L (5C612) for short. And again, I view its family and see that its brother (5C604) is better in everything from R<sub>DS(on)</sub> to Q charge.

But that is the most perplexing part. Mouser says that 5C604 is not recommended for new designs while 5C612 is new and recommended. Also, I found that 5C604 is half the price of 5C612.

I don't know now what I should go for: 5C612, which is more trusted, or 5C604, which is better on paper?

Comment: It depends if this is going to be a production or one-off device.  "Not recommended for new designs" means that the manufacturer is planning on phasing it out.  Even though the replacement is pin-compatible, the change in RDSon alone means that changing from the 604 to 612 means you're going to have to get rid of 33% more heat which at the rate at which you're making it is not going to be trivial.

Comment: "*most sellers on AliExpress claim that IRFS7534 hand*" Do not trust people selling a product they have no idea about. Besides, in use MOSFETs won't handle the currents listed in the datasheet anyways.

Comment: It's important to note that the datasheet current figures for MOSFETs are nigh meaningless. They represent the theoretical maximum current you could get if you could somehow keep the die at a perfect 25 °C with an infinite heatsink. Not the case, the die itself.

Comment: I know it's impossible to get the mosfet for maximum rated current but i type it to make comparison more clear

Comment: You should just go by RDson, thermal resistance, and the RDson rise vs temperature graph if that's your goal. The current numbers really only for comparing if you're glancing at a dozen MOSFET datasheets but if you're down to a handful there are better ways.

Comment: For tinkering AliExpress is fine. However, for serious projects, (such as perhaps a 3500W driver) the headaches you will save yourself by buying from a reputable distributor will probably make it worth the extra cost.

Comment: Unless you have a very involved cooling solution you will need to make sure that each mosfet only dissipates something like 1-5 Watts. They may be able to dissipate more for a short time, but as everything heats up, their ability to shed heat will decrease. In addition to Rds(on) you may want to look at the maximum junction temperature. If other parameters are close, but one transistor can withstand 175 C junction temperature and the other only 150 C, then the 175 C transistor will handle more power.

Comment: @Hearth some datasheets now provide Id max limits based on ambient temperature instead of case temperature. I agree that the Id limit based on Tc = 25C is, at best, a "figure of merit" to use comparing with other MOSFET's. I never look at Id max.

Comment: @mkeith It's worse than just using Tc--Frequently, they'll use Tj.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I move on searching and see some ESC from manufactures and see that
> they use NTMFS5C612L (5C612) for short. And again, I view its family
> and see that its brother (5C604) is better in everything from RDS(on)
> to Q charge.
>
> But that is the most perplexing part. Mouser says that 5C604 is not
> recommended for new designs while 5C612 is new and recommended. Also,
> I found that 5C604 is half the price of 5C612.

The manufacturer probably chose whichever FET they could get cheapest that would do the job. Perhaps they got a good deal on an older part, or they still have stocks from years ago. When they run out you might see a newer part in the next production run.

When selecting a part for your own design, consider what characteristics *you* need, and (particularly important these days) availability of the part and possible substitutes.

> I am designing an ESC (electronic speed controller) for a BLDC motor
> which is 3500W, 85A and 44V... I first found the IRFS7534, which has a
> 1.6 mohm RDS(on) and 255 amp. I viewed its family and found IRFS7530, which has a 1.15 mohm RDS(on) and 338 amps.

85 A<sup>2</sup> x 1.15 mΩ = 11 W of conduction loss. But at 125 °C the resistance is ~2.2 mΩ, then the power loss is ~16 W. At a duty cycle of 1/3 you have ~5 W loss per FET (more when switching loss is included). You might need to put 2 or more FETs in parallel to keep the temperature down.

> most sellers on AliExpress claim that IRFS7534 handles more current
> than IRFS7530

Don't trust anything you read on AliExpress, and don't buy from there unless you are willing to risk getting fake parts.

Comment: I will do that but you still don't answer my question which one should i use ?

Comment: The IRFS7530 has significantly lower RDSon which will probably be important to you. That's why I only calculated power loss for that FET and not the other one. However I note that both FETs are shown as 'obsolete' at Mouser, and neither they nor Digikey or Element 14 (the only suppliers I trust) have any in stock  Element 14 has estimated stock arrival in June 2023. I'm guessing you don't want to wait that long... In summary, I wouldn't recommend either one right now, but the IRFS7530 would be better than the IRFS7534 if you can get it.

Comment: 5C604 have 1.2 RDS on and 3 times faster in switching

Comment: Sorry I forgot that you were looking at 4 different FETs. The 5C612 is the only one currently available from Mouser (I haven't looked at other suppliers) so I guess that is your only choice out of these 4 FETs.